# Facebook like button doesn't count

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

I've been having a problem with facebook like count on my website. I've searched almost for two weeks without any fix. I've tried many things like Facebook debugger link and many differents codes but none works.

Since 3 of March my facebook button doesn't count anything even when my post does have likes like you can see here.
https://graph.facebook.com/http://welele.es/post/20132595952/una-foto-en-365-tiras-una-por-cada-dia-del-ano (2 shares)
http://welele.es/post/20132595952/una-foto-en-365-tiras-una-por-cada-dia-del-ano Not showing anything on like button
So the button works but it doesn't count...

The most weird thing about this is that I use the SAME code in other webpage probandoel.tumblr.com and it does work...
The only difference between this page and the one with the problems is that this one does not have facebook page linked to.

I just don't know what is the problem and it's getting my crazy... thanks in advance and excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem, is all Open Graph stuff... it seems that you have to prepare them to be succesfully filled... keep in mind this code I'm adding for TUMBLR.
But I suppose that you have to take those "meta property.." that you need for your website.

**Substitute every * with a <**

```
*meta property="og:site_name" content="http://welele.es/" />

{block:PostSummary}*meta property="og:title" content="{PostSummary} - {Name}" />{/block:PostSummary}

<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
{block:IndexPage}*meta property="og:url" content="http://welele.es/" />*meta property="og:title" content="{Name}" />{/block:IndexPage}

{block:PermalinkPage}*meta property="og:url" content="{Permalink}" />{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:Pages}*meta property="og:url" content="{URL}" /><meta property="og:title" content="{Label} - {Name}" />{/block:Pages}

{block:Posts}{block:Photo}*meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}" />{/block:Photo}
{block:Text}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" />{/block:Text}

{block:Quote}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" />{/block:Quote}

{block:Link}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" />{/block:Link}

{block:Chat}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" /> {/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" />{/block:Audio}

{block:Video}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}" /> {/block:Video}

{block:Answer}*meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}"/> {/block:Answer}
{/block:Posts}

*meta property="og:description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the 2nd question I have seen on this in the last week and you both have foreign language sites. I would suggest raising a Facebook bug report and include the repro steps. I think this is certainly more along the lines of an FB bug with foreign language sites. Your code is correct.